# SignatureAlgorithm to match RSA SHA256

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt, rsa

Salesforce server want to sign jwt with `RSA SHA256` - [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0)
and I cannot find the matching algorithm in `io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm` lib.
SignatureAlgorithm.RS256 description - `JWA algorithm name for RSASSA-PKCS-v1_5 using SHA-256` is it the right one?
Also there are 3 signing methods `Jwts.builder()` -

```
JwtBuilder io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, Key key)
JwtBuilder io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, byte[] secretKey)
JwtBuilder io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String secretKey)
```

I am not sure which one to use for `RSA SHA256`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HS256. Refer this [link](http://javadox.com/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.4/io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm.html)